# beautifulsoup parsing - dealing with superscript?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

This is the HTML segment I am trying to extract information from:

```
<td class="yfnc_tablehead1" width="74%">Market Cap (intraday)<font size="-1"><sup>5</sup></font>:</td><td class="yfnc_tabledata1"><span id="yfs_j10_aal">33.57B</span></td></tr>
```

On the webpage looks like:

> Market Cap (intraday)<sup>5</sup>:33.57B

What I have (doesn't work):

```
    HTML_MarketCap = soup.find('sup', text='5').find_next_sibling('span').text
```

How could I extract the 33.57B string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The span is not a sibling, it is a <del>child of the sibling of the grandparent</del> first cousin, once removed (thanks, 1.618).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
soup = bs("""<td class="yfnc_tablehead1" width="74%">Market Cap (intraday)
<font size="-1"><sup>5</sup></font>:</td><td class="yfnc_tabledata1">
<span id="yfs_j10_aal">33.57B</span></td></tr>""")

soup.find("sup", text="5").parent.parent.find_next_sibling("td").find("span").text
# u'33.57B'
```

Since you seem to have problems with it, here's my full test script (using [python-requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)), that reliably works for me:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s=AAL+Key+Statistics"

r = requests.get(url)

soup = bs(r.text)

HTML_MarketCap = soup.find("sup", text="5").parent.parent.find_next_sibling("td").find("span").text

print HTML_MarketCap
```

Comment: first cousin, once removed?  ;)

Comment: Made me chuckle, added it to the answer.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Would it be better to reference "Market Cap (intraday)" instead of the superscript?

Comment: Does my exact code work for you, i.e. when using my test string? What is more reliable depends on the page really.

Comment: The exact code doesn't work, but it could be the page itself. This is the page I am trying to scrape. http://finance.yahoo.com/q/ks?s=AAL+Key+Statistics

Comment: Works for me, wait a sec, I'll add a full script that works with the page, live.

Comment: that's really interesting. it must be because I am using an HTML file which is actually two webpages appended together. do you know if bs4 supports running things on two HTMLs appended together, or would it only be able to run on the first HTML.

Comment: Why don't you show me the exact source of some test website, using pastebin or so. Why do you append two pages together?

Comment: @L3viathan http://pastebin.com/JCEh0yp8 I concat'd the two together because I need to extract info on two different pages and insert it into a DB.

Comment: Then *don't* concat them and search in them seperately. I mean sure you can split them again in your script, but why join them in the first place. Don't do that.

Comment: Made a soup for each HTML and it worked flawlessly. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can simply use `find_next()` after locating the `<sup>5</sup>` element, like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = '''<td class="yfnc_tablehead1" width="74%">Market Cap (intraday)<font size="-1"><sup>5</sup></font>:</td><td class="yfnc_tabledata1"><span id="yfs_j10_aal">33.57B</span></td></tr>'''

soup  =BeautifulSoup(s)

sup = soup.find('sup', text='5')

sup.find_next('span')
Out[5]: <span id="yfs_j10_aal">33.57B</span>

sup.find_next('span').text
Out[6]: u'33.57B'


>>>help(sup.find_next)
```

> Help on method find_next in module bs4.element:
>
> find_next(self, name=None, attrs={}, text=None, **kwargs) method of
>   bs4.element.Tag instance
>       Returns the first item that matches the given criteria and
>       appears after this Tag in the document.