# Does BeautifulSoup still work on two concatenated HTML files?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, concatenation

I have a script that concatenates two HTML files into one. It literally just inserts the 2nd HTML code right after the first.

```
htmlfile1 = urllib.urlopen(url1)
htmlfile2 = urllib.urlopen(url2)

htmltext1 = htmlfile1.read()
htmltext2 = htmlfile2.read()

name=symbolslist[i]+'.html'    

o=open(name, "w")  
o.write(htmltext1)
o.write(htmltext2)
o.close()
```

In my other thread I seem to be having trouble parsing information on the 2nd HTML part using bs4, when the solution is correct.

I have no issue parsing information on the first HTML.

thread:
[beautifulsoup parsing - dealing with superscript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29737279/beautifulsoup-parsing-dealing-with-superscript)

Therefore I was wondering if Beautiful Soup works or not on concatenated HTML.

Comment: What is stopping you for trying it out and post back your results? I would try first with some test HTML files.

Comment: The solution in my other thread was correct (tested), but on my concatenated version it doesn't work.

Comment: BS doesn't do its own parsing, so I guess it depends which parser you're using. Is there a particular reason you *want* to do this?

Comment: It probably also depends on the type of HTML. For example, I just tried concatenating two copies of various different files; at least with the versions of bs4, lxml, and libxml2 I have, a valid HTML5 file doubled makes it barf, a valid HTML 4.01 transitional file silently eats the second HEAD but otherwise appears to work, a valid pre-HTML 3 file works just fine.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
Is what it says at the beginning of the file. It is two Yahoo Finance pages concatenated.

Comment: *"It is two Yahoo Finance pages concatenated"* - why?!

Comment: Without knowing which parser you're using, and which version, that doesn't help much. In fact, even knowing that wouldn't do much good, because I doubt any of the parsers thoroughly document what they do with illegal input like this beyond "we'll try to parse it, but no guarantees"…

Comment: I need information from two different pages to insert into my database. I figured it would be easier to parse through a concatenated version, than to parse through multiple shards

Comment: I'm using beautifulsoup4 to find strings in the HTML

Comment: *"I figured it would be easier to parse through a concatenated version"* - that seems like a strange assumption, why not just `for` loop over the relevant pages? *"I'm using beautifulsoup4"* - again, it **doesn't do its own parsing**. Which *parser* are you using it with?

Answer (score 1):

You should not expect this to work. Parsers expect to work with *one* HTML document.

HTML parsers *do* try and repair broken HTML, so you may get *some* results. However, since `id` attribute values must be unique in HTML, expect things to not work as you expect.

Just store your HTML in separate files and create separate `BeautifulSoup()` objects for them. You can have multiple *soup* objects in memory without issues.

Comment: It does not seem to work when using the `lxml` parser, and wrapping the concatenated file in a dummy tag either. I would have expected BeautifulSoup to load the whole file in this case, even if it is not HTML anymore but simply XML.

Comment: Actually it does work by wrapping the concatenated file into a dummy tag and not specifying any parser. The question is not much relevant in the provided example but sometimes working with concatenated HTML file is easier (e.g when you build them with a `cat` command in a loop after a `find`)

Comment: @EricBurel: not specifying a parser still picks an HTML parser.

Comment: Hmm its weird I do not have the same behaviour though, html did not work (and should not because the doc was containing multiple pages concatenated together). Doesn't it have some kind of autoselection?

Comment: @EricBurel: Beautifulsoup supports three different HTML parsers; each of these deals with broken HTML differently. Concatenating HTML documents, even with a new parent container, invariably produces broken HTML. Next, BeautifulSoup will use lxml as the default if installed, then html5lib if installed, then the standard library html.parser. If you specify a different parser as the second argument, you are likely to see different outcomes. See https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#specifying-the-parser-to-use